# Display gallery popup outside iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I read some thread in here, but I haven't found a good solution for gallery item. I am not expery in jQuery so please bear with me here. I have code to display one image outside iframe. But my goal is to add left/right arrow to scroll through my gallery.

I have this script

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fancybox').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            parent.$.fancybox({         
                type : "image", // force type of content to image
                href: this.href,
                title: this.title,
                helpers: {
                    title: { type: 'inside' },
                    overlay: {
                        opacity: 0.3
                    } // overlay
                    //, buttons: {}
                } // helpers
            }); // fancybox
        }); // click
    }); 
</script>
```

and my HTML code is

```
<a  rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg" title="aaasdasdasd"><img alt="" src="thumbnails/01.jpg"/></a>
<a  rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="images/02.jpg" title="bbsdfsdfsdfdsf"><img alt="" src="thumbnails/02.jpg"/></a>
```

FancyBox pop up works. But I would like to add arrows to scroll along my "gallery item". I tried adding gallery code 
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
right above 
    parent.$.fancybox({

but the popup just disappear.

Adding 
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        padding     : 0,
        margin      : [20, 60, 20, 60] // Increase left/right margin

also make the popup disappear.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create your gallery elements manually first so try

```
var gallery = [];
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").each(function (i) {
        var item = {
            href: this.href,
            title: this.title
        };
        gallery.push(item);
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            parent.$.fancybox(gallery, {
                // API options
                index: i, // starts gallery from clicked item
                type: "image", // force type of content to image
                helpers: {
                    title: {
                        type: 'inside'
                    }
                } // helpers
            }); // fancybox
            return false;
        }); // on
    }); // each
}); // ready
```

Comment: I used your code. But now the fancybox stop popping up. How come there is return false there?
Is there another jQuery can do this? I tried Visuallight box and magnific pop but both don't work. Only Fancybox is the closest. Thanks for the time first.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine http://jsfiddle.net/uj0zLco4/ the `return false` voids the default action because we are firing fancybox programmatically after the `click` event.

Comment: Sorry I was in the middle of typing the message. It works on firefox, IE, safari. But Chrome is having problem making it to pop up. Any idea?
if I replace `parent.$.fancybox(gallery, {` to  `$.fancybox(gallery, {` and Chrome works as pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for FancyBox showing Gallery image outside iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var gallery = [];

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".fancybox").each(function(i) {

            var item = {
                href: this.href,
                title: this.title
            };
            gallery.push(item);     

            $(this).on("click", function() {    
            parent.$.fancybox(gallery, {
                index: i, // starts gallery from clicked item
                type: "image", // force type of content to image
                helpers: {
                    title: {
                        type: 'inside'
                    },
                    overlay: {
                        opacity: 0.3
                    } // overlay
                } // helpers
            }); // fancybox
            return false;
        }); // click
    });
});
</script>
```

and the html code is like

```
<a  rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg" title="test1"><img alt="" src="thumbnails/01.jpg"/></a>
<a  rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="images/02.jpg" title="test2"><img alt="" src="thumbnails/02.jpg"/></a>
```

this works on IE, firefox, safari, but not Chrome.

Comment: works for me, at least in Chrome Version 36.0.1985.143 m + (Windows)